# Facebook app - "Url was not found"

Tags: facebook, url, ssl

I have a problem with my Facebook app but impossible for me to understand why ! 
I have correctly filled all the urls but I have always the message :

"The requested URL /~dcontracvw/lamission/ was not found on this server."

If I try to connect with this URL : https://ssl7.ovh.net/~dcontracvw/lamission/ it's work perfectly…

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Your app is loaded into the Facebook iframe via a POST request – and your URL responds with a 404 if the request method is POST.

Comment: OK thanks ! How to fix that ?

Comment: The URL you have given is just a directory listing – I suppose that is not really what you want to be the “content” of your app anyway. Once you point the setting to a real script that accepts POST requests, that problem should be gone automatically.